# Reading a JSON file error in Pandas for text extraction

Tags: python, json, pandas, lda, topic-modeling

Doing topic modeling to extract the hidden topic from JSON file using LDA where I am getting the following error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-ff05500d50e8> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_json("E:\Andias-Alam\aug17.json")
      2 print(df.target_names.unique())
      3 df.head()

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json.py in parse(self)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)

ValueError: Expected object or value
```

while importing the data using pandas.read_json I am facing the error

```
df = pd.read_json("E:\Andias-Alam\aug17.json")
print(df.target_names.unique())
df.head()
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of what your json looks like please?

Comment: It seems like the file is empty

Comment: actually, I was doing something wrong that in my file there was no attribute called target_names.

now the code looks like :

`df = pd.read_json("E:\\aug17.json")
print(df.content.unique())
df.head()`

got the desired output- Thanks